# How does the Clojure compiler generates JVM bytecode?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, clojure, compilation

What library/api does the  Clojure compiler (which is just a jar/java application) uses to generate the JVM bytecode? I'm curious since the bytecode is being generated at runtime by java and not javac, so its a java program that outputs jvm bytecode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clojure uses a Java library called [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) to generate bytecode. A fork of a part of the lib is embedded into the clojure project here: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/tree/master/src/jvm/clojure/asm

Comment: It's actually a subset of ASM. As part of Clojure 1.6, the subset was recently updated to ASM 4.1 in master.

Answer (score 3):

> How does the Clojure compiler generates JVM bytecode?

It is just Java programming (unless they have bootstrapped their code generator to Clojure ... which seems unlikely).  As a gross simplification<sup>1</sup>, is opening a file, writing out the code in "classfile" format as specified by the JVM spec, and then closing the file.  (Or writing the code to a ByteArrayOutputStream or equivalent.)

For the record, there is nothing qualitatively different between what the Clojure compiler is doing and the Java compiler *can* do if you call it at runtime.  But obviously there will be differences in the fine-grain details, because of differences in the languages, and different ideas and priorities for the respective developers.

---

<sup>1 - If you want to know how code generators in general work, read a textbook on compiler writing.  For all of the gory details of how Clojure does it, look at the source code ...</sup>

Comment: The one exception I know of regarding Clojure and Java bytecode generation is Clojure locals clearing, which has no Java analog iirc.

Comment: There is a CinC (Clojure in Clojure) project, that would generate Clojure byte code without using any Java code, but it is not yet mature.